# Selecting the closest option in a select element, in Angular.js

Tags: select, model, angularjs, controller

I have a SELECT like this in my template:

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue">
    <option>$5</option>
    <option>$10</option>
    <option>$20</option>
    <option>$50</option>
    <option>$100</option>
</select>
```

Then in the controller, I retrieve some value from a web service and I do:

```
$scope.selectedValue = somevalue;
```

This works if `somevalue` is one of the options in the select element. However, if it's not, the select is simply blank. So what I'd like to do is select the closest value to `somevalue`. For example, if I retrieve $9, I would select the $10 option.

I know how to do it using jQuery, however this is not really the Angular way.

Is there any easy way to do that in Angular?

Comment: You will have to create your own logic for "selecting the closest option". Instead of executing `$scope.selectedValue = somevalue;` you could first call this logic to fetch the nearest if not the same value from the options and then set it to the `$scope.selectedValue`

Comment: @user2104976, what would be the best way to get all the options from the select? I know how to do it with jQuery and DOM manipulations but as I understand this is to be avoided in Angular.js controllers. Just curious what would be the proper Angular way to do it?

Comment: The best approach would be to create a model in your scope which holds the values of the options. You can check out the `ng-options` directive which takes the options to be displayed. You can find the documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select). This is the AngularJS way to do it. Thus your model already has the options that will be displayed which you can then use inside your controller. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You can check the comments in that documentation too to understand how to go about with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user2104976, that's what I will do. Feel free to add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.